# Сделать переменные полями класса

Tags: python, классы

Есть два метода: - один на регистрацию пользователя, второй на авторизацию с данными, полученными из первой функции.
Не могу подружить, чтобы функция авторизации подхватывала логин, пароль из первой функции. Если вынести в 1 функцию - то все работает

```
from requests.models import Response
from lib.my_requests import MyRequests
import requests
from lib import assertions
from lib.base_case import BaseCase
from lib.assertions import Assertions
import allure
      
@allure.epic("Tests for user edits")
class TestUserEdit(BaseCase):
    @allure.description("this test for success create user")
    def test_user_register(self):
        # REGISTER
        register_data = self.prepare_register_data()
        response1 = MyRequests.post("/user/", data=register_data)
   
        Assertions.assert_code_status(response1, 200)
        Assertions.json_has_key(response1, "id")
      
        email = register_data['email']
        first_name = register_data['firstName']
        password = register_data['password']
        user_id = self.get_answer(response1, "id")
      
        self.saved_email = email
        self.saved_user_id = user_id
        self.saved_password = password
      
        print("REG")
        print(response1.content)
        print(response1.text)
        print(response1.cookies)
         
    def test_login(self):
  
        login_data = {
            'email': self.saved_email,
            'password': self.saved_password
        }
      
        response2 = MyRequests.post("/user/login", data=login_data)
        auth_sid = self.get_cookie(response2, "auth_sid")
        token = self.get_header(response2, "x-csrf-token")
        print(response2.cookies)
        print(response2.headers)
        print(response2.content)
```

Comment: а в чем проблема то? можете приложить код ошибки

Comment: а, кажись понял, т.к это тестовые функции, результат работы одной не влияет на результат работы другой. в таком случае можете присваивать переменные не экземпляру, а самому классу. `TestUserEdit.saved_email` = `email`

Comment: Спасибо, это и требовалось. Работает)